# Firebase Hosting SSL Handshake exception on Android 4.4

Tags: android, firebase, ssl, android-4.4-kitkat, firebase-hosting

We are facing an issue while using Firebase Hosting to retrieve some resources.

```
10-05 17:20:13.524: E/cocos2d-x debug info(11334): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x587e3bd0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
10-05 17:20:13.524: E/cocos2d-x debug info(11334): error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x558ebd44:0x00000000)
```

This didn't occur yesterday (04-Oct-2017), and only occurred on Android 4.4 and older.

We tried to switch to a non HTTPS host, and it works. However, we can't make modifications to the released version that users already installed now, and we want to keep using Firebase Hosting for our app.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm far from certain but I'm guessing this comes from the server part not accepting SSLv2 anymore and the old android clients not being able to use TLSv1+... If security is important to you, you should really keep the server that way and upgrade the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did recently make a change to Firebase Hosting to stop supporting old encryption protocols. Please follow up through Firebase support on this issue and we'll see if we can help you out.

Comment: Thank you. After double checking the docs, we came to a solution to enable old SSL support in the code. This solved the issue.

Comment: @PhongDinh Could you tell me how you did it or a source where to find it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issues seems to be not in the server. Your old android device might not have updated ssl/tls support. Latest/safe version is tls1.3 AFAIK

See if you can update the browser version on the device and ensure the device supports tls1.3

Also ensure the device clock is correct